# Android.Espresso: How check text size of TextView in SP?

Tags: android-espresso

here xml:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbaTitleTextView"
            style="@style/textViewOneLine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp"          
           />
```

I need to write Espresso test check that **TextView** has font size (in **SP**) = 13.

So here test:

```
@Test
    public void toolBarTextSize() {
        onView(withId(R.id.toolbaTitleTextView)).check(matches(withFontSize(13)));
    }
```

Here matcher:

```
public static Matcher<View> withFontSize(final float expectedSize) {
        return new BoundedMatcher<View, View>(View.class) {

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View target) {
                if (!(target instanceof TextView)) {
                    return false;
                }
                TextView targetEditText = (TextView) target;
                return targetEditText.getTextSize() == expectedSize;
            }

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with fontSize: ");
                description.appendValue(expectedSize);
            }
        };
    }
```

But I get error, because size in **pixels**.

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with fontSize: <13.0F>' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with fontSize: <13.0F>
Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131296624, res-name=toolbaTitleTextView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@13f0b, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Sign in, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

But I need in **SP**. How I can check text size in **SP**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just convert your size in pixels to the scales pixels. So, your matcher should look like this:

```
public static Matcher<View> withFontSize(final float expectedSize) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, View>(View.class) {

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View target) {
            if (!(target instanceof TextView)) {
                return false;
            }
            TextView targetEditText = (TextView) target;
            float pixels = targetEditText.getTextSize();
            float actualSize = pixels / target.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
            return Float.compare(actualSize, expectedSize) == 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with fontSize: ");
            description.appendValue(expectedSize);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `pixels / target.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity` will give a very high precision value. Wrapping this whole thing into `Math.round(...)` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use this class to getting equivalency for font size

```
class FontSizeMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<View> {

    private final float mExpectedFontSize;
    private float actualFontSize;

    public FontSizeMatcher(float fontSize) {
        super(View.class);
        mExpectedFontSize = fontSize;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {

        if (!(item instanceof TextView)) {
            return false;
        }

        actualFontSize = ((TextView) item).getTextSize();
        return mExpectedFontSize == actualFontSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("Text Size did not match " + mExpectedFontSize + " was " + actualFontSize);
    }
}
```

To use this,

```
onView(withId(R.id.btn)).check(matches(new FontSizeMatcher(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_test))));
```

The only difference between the ticked answer and this one is that this uses an internal method to get the float value.

Comment: FYI you could have used `BoundedMatcher` instead of `TypeSafeMatcher` to avoid having to do the `instanceof` call yourself

Answer (score 0):

Building on @JimitPatel's answer but using `BoundedMatcher` (and also using Kotlin):

```
fun hasFontSizeDimen(@DimenRes fontSizeDimen: Int): Matcher<View> {
    return object : BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView::class.java) {
        override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
            description?.appendText("has expected font size")
        }

        override fun matchesSafely(item: TextView?): Boolean {
            if (item == null) return false
            val expectedFontSize = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
                .targetContext
                .resources
                .getDimension(fontSizeDimen)
            val actualFontSize = item.textSize
            return (expectedFontSize == actualFontSize)
        }
    }
}
```